# Read a very long string from console using Java Scanner takes time?

Tags: java, string, long-integer, java.util.scanner

Currently I'm creating a console program that read a one line with very long String with java Scanner

sample data is more like this

50000 integer in one line separated by white-space,

```
"11 23 34 103 999 381 ....." until 50000 integer
```

This data is entered by user via console not from a File

here's my code

```
        System.out.print("Input of integers : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String Z = sc.nextLine();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("String Z created in "+(end-start)+"ms, Z character length is "+Z.length()+" characters");
```

Then I execute, as the result I've got this

```
String Z created within 49747ms, Z character length is 194539 characters
```

My question is why it takes a long time?
Is there any faster way to read a very long string?

I have tried buffered reader, but not much different..

```
String Z created within 41881ms, Z character length is 194539 characters
```

Comment: I think Time taken might not be accurate as it also includes the `wait` time - time it waits for user to enter data and hit enter key

Comment: yes it is, the problem is not in there..it's around +-97459ms only for executing sc.nextLine().. I copy pasted the data so it takes around 10-30ms for only inserting the data ..

Comment: I get 60ms here for a 200k line fed to the console via `cat` (would be `type` on Windows, iirc). My prime suspect remains the passing of data.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like scanner uses a regular expression to match the end of line - this is likely causing the inefficiency, especially since you're matching regex against a 200k length String.

The pattern used is, effectively, .*(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])|.+$

Comment: I change sc.nextLine() to sc.next(pattern), that pattern gives an error Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 *( |[   ])|.+$ ^

Comment: I said effectively - it's a copy and paste from the Scanner source that merges two defined constants.  Regardless, there's a regex being applied to the order of 10^6 characters - that's a lot of operations.  You might be better off reading the values in from a file.

Comment: Or use a BufferedReader(System.in) and readLine() instead of a Scanner.

Comment: @mcfinnigan But I needs to read it from a console :)..thanks for your answer before

Comment: @SkipHead it's better than scanner "String Z created within 41881ms, Z character length is 194539" but still takes time, I need something more fast..

Comment: But if I `cat` a 200k line into the above, the Scanner reads the line in reasonable 60ms. That seems to indicate the problem is rather in the passing of input from the console than the regex.

Comment: @DanielFischer - interesting! So I could be on totally the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be memory allocation, as it reads the line, it fills char buffer. And it gets larger and larger and needs to copy all so far readed text again and again. Each time it makes internal buffer Ntimes larger, so it is not atrociously slow, but for your huge line, it still is slow.

And processing of regexp itself does not help too. But my guess is that realocation and copying is the source of slowdown.

And maybe it needs to do GC to free memory to aquire, so another slowdown.

You can test my hypothesis by copying of Scanner and changing BUFFER_SIZE to equal your line length (or larger, to be sure).